# How to show docker container rm/stop commands log

Tags: docker, logging

Any way to show docker container rm/stop commands log ?

via docker vm console

or

via portainer ?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/#read-the-logs

Comment: sudo cat /var/log/messages | grep "docker container" can't show anything

Comment: `docker events` can help you